# Uploading via PHP

Tags: php, html, storage, uploading

This is quite a complex question, I'm sure. I've tried trawling the internet for some time now, but perhaps I'm not wording my question correctly when googling.

I have a HTML form that requests the following information;

- Users name
- Title of post
- Image to upload
- Comments

I have already created a PHP script that captures the image and uploads it to a DIR, but what I'd also like to do is capture the text fields and then render the data (pic and text) and post to a webpage using formatting that I have set.

How easy is this to achieve?

PHP: http://www.mediafire.com/?bxze6j9kn048uzb

```
<?php
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 512)) {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        } else {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
      }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```

Form: http://www.mediafire.com/?bao8n2uftu7ma34

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" maxlength="50" size=40">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="3000" cols="30" rows="12"></textarea>
    <input type="image" src="/Images/upload_button.png" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Best,

Rob.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code here instead please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the data (text) somewhere like an [database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), and link the uploaded file to right text. Take a look at for example [mongodb](http://mongodb.org/) and [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)(which you probably have on you web hotel)

Mysql getting started http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/everything-you-need-to-get-started-with-mysql/ or http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp